Why the LED heats up and fails to pass the controlling information further?
Intro
I'm designing my own macro keyboard with 3x5 rows of RGB-LED backlit buttons and two encoders. I use SK6812 (WS-2812B-like) mini RGB LEDs to backlight the buttons.
TL;DR
After turning on the keyboard, consistently LEDs after first 3 or 4 stop properly receiving instructions and start to freak out (stay unlit, change color to some random one) etc.
I have replaced the 3rd, 4th and 5th LEDs, but the best result I achieved was ~1 minute of proper work and the same issue returned. Finally I have checked with a thermal camera that 4th LED heats up to 50oC, what might cause the issue. I have no idea though, why does it happen, why is it always 4th LED, how to diagnose the issue properly and how to fix it.
Link
Link to the repository containing schematics (KiCad), firmware and software: https://gitlab.com/spook/OpenMacroKeyboard (note, this is mainly software project, keyboard designs are supposed to be only examples)
Parts

RP2040-Plus (Waveshare 23503) - Raspberry Pi Pico compatible microcontroller (but with USB-C)
SK6812 LEDs (I found the datasheet here - unsure though if it is a valid one). These are RGB, adressed LEDs seemingly compatible with popular WS2812 protocol. They do seem to work, except that they use GRB addressing instead of RGB.
BOB-12009 logic levels converter (Board uses 3v3 logic, LEDs - 5v)
CherryMX-compatible keys, simple encoders (most likely not relevant)

Design details (relevant)
The schematic looks like following. Please forgive wrong device reference names, I'm a relative beginner in electrical engineering.

The front of the PCB looks like following:

The back of the PCB looks like following (this is where LEDs are being connected):

For easier understanding: logic for LEDs comes from PCB's 2nd pin - it goes to LV1 (Low Voltage 1) input of the BOB-12009 and then its HV1 (High Voltage 1) is connected to first LED's DIN (Data In) pin.
LEDs are being powered by the VCC pin of the microcontroller board, which is hardwired to USB's +5V. The same goes to BOB-12009's HV (High Voltage) reference pin.
LV (Low Voltage) of the BOB-12009 is connected to 3v3 pin on the microcontroller board. (By the way, is there a need of doing so if there is no backwards transmission?
Front photo (after all fix attempts):

Back photo (after all fix attempts):

Comment: I have ripped off one of the pads during attempts to replace LEDs (now I have some experience, so I managed not to rip off any more pads, sigh), so I had to replace it with a wire (relevant?)
The (almost) cut wire is a 3v3 reference to BOB-12009, but it is not cut (checked with a multimeter).
The problem
This is the desired result (color pattern selected just for testing purposes, in general it is controlled from the PC via COM/USB)

This is how it looked just a minute later (it changed on its own without sending any transmission from the PC):

This is how the board looks on thermal camera before powering up:

This is how the board looks a dozen seconds after powering up (keep in mind that regular camera and thermal camera are misaligned, so the thermal image may be a little bit off to the contours)

What did I try
Initially only first 3 LEDs show the valid colors.

I have soldered a 47uF capacitor to the C1 location on the schematic (no effect)
I have replaced 3rd LED with a new one (from what I remember, now the problem switched to the 4th LED)
I have replaced 4th LED (no effect)
I have replaced 5th LED (no effect)
I have added a 220 Ohm resistor between BOB-12009's HV1 logic output and LED_1 DIN (no effect)
I have replaced 4th LED again - the keyboard worked for a minute or so as expected, then the problem returned.

From my observations it is not really a faulty LED rather than LED becoming faulty after some time, what might suggest a PCB problem (but what kind? How can I check it?).
Possible solutions

Initially I expected interference from PC's USB connection so in the next design I have added space for SMD (1206) capacitors between VCC and GND just before LEDs
I have added space for SMD (1206) resistor between BOB-12009's HV1 and LED_1's DIN
I have added space fpr SMD (1206) resistor after LED_15's DOUT and GND (that's after inspecting the LED's datasheet - although it does not show what the last resistor in the DIN/DOUT chain is supposed to be connected to)
I have made the wires twice as thick (0.4mm as compared to 0.2mm)

This is the layout of bottom of the PCB after changes (the changes themselves are marked with red arrows):

I'm unsure if those changes will help though.

Edit In response to answers and comments
Current drain
I have measured that a single LED consumes around 40 mA. To not exceed USB restrictions, I have programmatically capped the maximum brightness at half. It means that all 15 diodes should consume around 0.3A when all lit white, which indeed seems to be the case:

Changes
I have redesigned the board according to your suggestions and added power planes. I also added capacitors just next to diodes; they didn't seem to make too much sense just connected to the power planes next to diodes, so I have set up exclusion zones to ensure that the capacitor actually precedes the diodes:

With the power planes I could also rip all GND and VBUS wires. Neat :)
I have removed the 47uF capacitor since it didn't do any good.
I have also removed the resistor at the end of the LED line (LED_15 DOUT).
I have also further increased thickness of all wires, now they are 0.5mm thick.

Edit: In response to comments
I have redesigned the LED and the bypass capacitor once again. I hope this version finally matches your suggestions.


Not sure if this is your only problem, but the datasheet talks about the importance of thermal management to the reliability of the LEDs, but you didn't use any planes to provide a way for heat to leave. If you set the LEDs to low brightness and all the same color do they still fail the same way?

Can you test each LED before soldering it to the circuit board?

Try removing the suspect LED and bypassing DIN to DOUT with a jumper. Do things work ok then?

Just noticed in the revised board that your capacitors don't directly connect to the LED ground which will prevent them from decoupling. Once you replace the power and ground traces with planes, put each cap from LED vdd pin to gnd pin with as short a loop as possible.

@spook What you did with the LED  bypass caps is not great. You still have long narrow wires. The supply plane does connect to cap directy but there's 1cm narrow wire to LED. The GND via connects to LED almost directly via narrow trace, but from the LED there is a long narrow track to capacitor, with even two vias on it. It would likey be better if cap directly connects to the planes, more closer to LED pins.

(As a comment since this is not a direct answer to your question). Your new layout doesn't address the issues raised.  You still have a very long path for your decoupling capacitor, and while you added planes you did so in a way that prevents that from providing any cooling of your device. Instead, directly connect both VDD and GND to a plane with no traces on either pin.  Turn off thermal reliefs on both plane properties in KiCAD so you get good thermal contact.  Put the capacitor directly between the two plains, route the data signal between the pads all on one layer.

@Justme, would it be possible for you to provide some kind of drawing of what you are suggesting? I'm a little bit lost in your description :(

@Spook There are plenty of good resources on the web about placing and routing bypass caps. I would like to point out that your current implementation might be good enough already, but you can easily get rid of the two extra vias on the trace going to capacitor. You are routing a ground wire through a ground plane already so they are the same net/wire anyway so cap might go with one via to plane.

Draw the line from VDD to the capacitor and then from the capacitor to the GND pin that current would take to go around the circuit. You want that current loop to be short, but you've doubled back on itself.

@user1850479, the final design actually contains a "shortcut" through vias (the only other way would be to pass the data line temporarily through the second side of the board - as LEDs are surface-mounted - but I think that it wouldn't be possible in all cases). I have edited the post to include updated screenshot.

You could probably put the capacitor over the data line and avoid the vias entirely.

@user1850479, it turned out in the end that the GND/VCC planes were enough and I didn't even needed the capacitors. Everything works now with a top of 29oC. Thanks for the help :)

I think there are many things not entirely correct.
First of all, it is a miracle that you can use that logic level shifter at all. Most people here simply ask why it does not work level translating a high speed bus for ARGB LEDs. But that's clearly not the problem.
The second problem is that you have no bypass caps on the LEDs or nowhere else either. The 47 uF electrolytic is useless at the frequencies required by the board and also far away with narrow track from everything that needs current and needs it fast.
Third problem relates, the LEDs consume a hefty amount of current, but the PCB tracks are really narrow for passing a lot of current to LEDs. The tracks should not even be tracks but maybe a solid supply and ground planes to pass a lot of current without voltage dropping. Anyway, wider tracks with ability to pass more current would have been essentially free as all the copper is etched out.
Final problem might be current consumption and current profile.
USB specs do not allow more than 10uF of capacitance on VBUS so it's rather unknown how much there is on the MCU board but the 47uF violates the specs for sure. The LEDs seem to be rated 12mA per color so 36mA per module so more than 500mA when all are turned on white. I suppose the MCU board does not consume much, but with USB, there are a few things. You can't consume more than 100mA unless the device have negotiated with the PC that it needs more than 100mA. Also, you cannot request more than 500mA. The Type-C connector does not change that.
How the MCU board works is unknown as they don't share the schematics.

I mentioned bypassing DIN to DOUT on the suspect LED as an initial test, though I think your problems are more fundamental than that.
Recognize that RGB LEDs draw a fair amount of current. At first look your layout isn't up to the task of providing enough power to your LED array, so what may be happening is that you have a ground shift leading to a latch-up, which could cause the LED's current to freak out like you're seeing.
If you want to experiment with your current PCB, do a couple of things:

Add thicker wire overlaying your GND and VDD traces
Add 0.1uF bypass at each LED

When you revise your PCB, replace your GND and VDD areas with planes, and place bypass caps at each LED.
